# Strip image URLs from data using Regex in Classic ASP

Tags: regex, asp-classic

I was just wondering how to write a function which takes a string and strips out everything which isn't an image URL?

I presume the best course would be regEx but I'm not sure.

The content type doesn't matter, just needs to be an URL with extension of either jpg, gif or png.

I did have a go but to no avail.

```
Function RegExResults(strTarget, strPattern)

    Set regEx = New RegExp
    regEx.Pattern = strPattern
    regEx.Global = true
    Set RegExResults = regEx.Execute(strTarget)
    Set regEx = Nothing

End Function

Set arrResults = RegExResults(data, "(http://)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\.])*")

For each result in arrResults
    Response.Write(result.Submatches(0)) & "<br>"
Next

Set arrResults = Nothing
```

Comment: How is a "image URL" defined?

Comment: The content type doesn't matter, just needs to be an URL with extension of either jpg, gif or png.

Answer (score 0):

As many people have mentioned before in other questions dealing with regex and URL's in a block of text it is almost impossible to do 100% accurately via regex.  Check out this post by the [Regex Guru](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/) for a better understanding of why.  His solution is probably the best one to use in this situation given the limited details you have provided.  You would need to modify the ending to ensure that you only obtain image files, by specifying the correct extensions in the regex, if that is all you are looking for.

```
\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$])(?:\.jpg|\.png|ETC.)
```

This is using the regex found in the link, and just replace the ETC. with more or statements containing the different file extensions you want to look for.

Comment: Thats not working could you have a look at the code above and see if that is correct?

Comment: It is working for me, just tested it on a few different regex engines... as explained in the link, this should be used as case insensitive or else it may not work, have you tried that?

Comment: I was referring to my code above specifically is my functionality correct with your RegEx? Thanks

Comment: Oh sorry... I've never worked with ASP, so all I can help with is the RegEx issue.  Gonna have to find someone else for the ASP stuff!